# Out of order examples in Megillah

Tags: tractate-megillah

In Masechet Megillah 18a (I think), the Gemara brings 3 examples of learning different words from the maidservant of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi. Then they go on to bring an example of learning a word they didn’t know from an Arab. Then they bring yet one more example of learning a word from the maidservant of Rabbi Yehuda HaNasi. So my question is why not bring first all the maidservant examples and then the Arab one last, why specifically insert this Arab example in the middle of the maidservant examples

Comment: It's 18a, and there are 5 examples.

Comment: @shmosel 5 in total, *first* there’s 3 of the maidservant and then one Arab and then back to the maidservant

Comment: Maybe it puts the two cases that arise from a Mishnah together, then the two cases from kesuvim and then the case from neviim.

Comment: @Chatzkel interesting theory, but it’s a weird order. There’s two Mishnahs, then mishlei, Tehillim, then Isaiah. Very random order.

Comment: Note that in Rosh Hashanah 26b the same narrative is given, but there the four with Rebbi's maidservant are all together, followed by the one with the Arab.